# What is the optimal way to detect press outside of a component like a dropdown menu?

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu, dropdown, pressable, touchablewithoutfeedback

I have a custom dropdown button which opens a dropdown menu in React Native. To handle the state of dropdown I use Redux Toolkit. What most confuses me is the approach to detect clicks outside that dropdown menu to dispatch an action to hide the dropdown.

I have searched for possible solutions and here's the list of possible solutions I came across so far:

### 1. Wrapping inside TouchableWithoutFeedback Component

Wrap the whole app or screen inside `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component to detect presses outside the element. If user presses the Touchable component then the press is surely outside the dropdown menu so we can close the dropdown using `onPress` event handler.

##### Cons:

- If users presses somewhere outside both dropdown menu and `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, like another custom button, text input component etc. then the press event will be handled by these other children components and will not reach to `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component's `onPress` handler. To make sure dropdown menu is hidden after user presses these other components, I will have to manually handle their specific press handlers. This will cause in less managable code and a lot of code duplication.
- `FlatList` or other `ScrollView` like scrollable components have a buggy scroll behaviour. Sometimes scroll events don't register by these components.

### 2. Setting hitSlope/hitBox of dropdown menu to very high number

When we set the hitSlope or hitBox prop of dropdown menu's outer Touchable component we can register the presses outside the menu. But this is an ugly approach in my opnion because it may overlap with other pressable components and could cause bugs.

#### Cons

- Ugly code
- Huge hitSlope may overlap with other pressable components and could cause bugs

Comment: Listen to the `document` element and check if the dropdown is the parent.

Comment: @Mycolaos wish it would work the same way in React Native, that would be a lot easier. In RN, there's no document object and can't really detect if something is clicked or not by event.target object. (afaik)

Comment: My bad, I'm not really familiar with RN, but it's interesting an issue!
1) Couldn't you leverage focus & blur?
2) What about this lib https://github.com/jakex7/react-native-click-outside ?

Comment: @Mycolaos Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately I can't set onFocus or onBlur methods on Views or Touchable components. For the 2nd solution, what it basically does is the samething I wrote in 1st possible solution. It gives a component which is in the end another TouchableWithoutFeedback to wrap your whole app so when user presses it you know it is a press outside your component, works similar. But if user doesn't press on that wrapper Touchable or your component but something like another Touchable or Input, then the wrapper misses that press event.